# sw-precache-config, ignore path does not work?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have following sw-precache-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'index.html',
    'manifest.json',
    'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*',
  ],
  navigateFallback: 'index.html',
  runtimeCaching: [{
    urlPattern: /.+\/api\/.+/,
    handler: 'networkOnly',
  }],
};
```

I have SPA application with service-worker (generated using above mentioned config) to cache resources.

When I open myapp/api/route without cached resources (first visit of website), it works fine.

If I open myapp's main page, browser caches resources and subsequent requests to myapp/api/route cause problems (layout of myapp's main page is generated but without data).

When I clear browsers' cache (Chrome - Developer Tools - tab Application - Cache storage - Clear) I can open myapp/api/route again.

So my problem is: how can I force browser to ignore service-worker.js for all "myapp/api/*" routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to simply ignore requests containing the pattern.

```
// service-worker.js   
self.onfetch = evt => {
  let path = new URL(evt.request.url).pathname;
  if(path.startsWith('/myapp/api')) {
    // these requests will be networked
    return;
  }
  // Handle other requests here
};
```

Comment: service-worker is generated automatically, so how can I force it to be generated?

Comment: @Vitaliy This should be another topic. You can search for the way to update a service worker. I think there're already answers for it on SO.